# How to send data to Google Sheets as base64 string using Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script

- I am new to `Apps Script` and I am trying to implement where I am taking an input through `Google Sheets` by using `Apps Script`. The user gets prompted with a HTML form through which the user uploads a `PDF` file.
- The file is further saved in a google drive and further used for processing the `PDF`.
- One way of importing `csv` file into `Google Sheets` is uploading the output to the `Google Drive` and then importing the `CSV` to a new sheets. I am able to achieve this.
- My question is can I cut the `middle-ware` of `Google Drive` and directly give `base-64` string as an input maybe by using `callback` url to the Google Sheets and the output is generated?

Comment: I can be wrong, but as far as I can tell the `UrlFetchApp` does about this thing: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app?hl=en

Comment: But that takes an ```api``` link as far as I have understood. I am talking about making a ```callback``` to the ```apps script``` containing just the ```base-64``` string.

Comment: Not sure if full understand your workflow. You have a csv file and you want to put it on the sheet? You can do in directly from local script (Node.js, Python, etc) via Sheets API without uploading on Drive. What the pdf files has to do with this?

Comment: Supposing you have a base64 encoded string, could you perhaps do something like `Utilities.parseCsv(Utilities.newBlob(Utilities.base64decode(base64String)).getDataAsString());`

Comment: Getting error ```Error Exception: Could not parse text.```. For the method there is just a little typo it is ```base64Decode``` and not ```base64decode```.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

```
function myFunction() {
  var csv_string = 'aa,bb,cc\n11,22,33'; // original csv string

  var base64data = Utilities.base64Encode(csv_string); // encoded string
  console.log(base64data);
  
  var decoded = Utilities.base64Decode(base64data); // decoded string
  console.log(decoded);
  
  var string = Utilities.newBlob(decoded).getDataAsString(); // csv string
  console.log({string});

  var array = Utilities.parseCsv(string) // 2d array
  console.log(array)
}
```

Reference: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities/utilities?hl=en#parseCsv(String)

**Update**

It works fine with your CSV:

```
function myFunction() {

  var csv_string = `Transaction_Date,Particulars,Cr_Dr,Amount,Balance
01-APR-2017,B/F,,,"3,99,068.72"
03-Apr-2017,NEFT-MAHENDRA HARDWARE,Cr,"1,31,427.00","2,67,641.72"
05-Apr-2017,NEFT-INTER DECOR,Cr,"1,01,607.00","1,66,034.72"
07-Apr-2017,INSPECTION CHARGES,Dr,721.00,"1,66,755.72"
10-Apr-2017,BY CLG--            5484,Cr,"90,115.00","76,640.72"
11-Apr-2017,INDORE MAIN 387 GOVT,Dr,299.00,"76,939.72"
11-Apr-2017,INDORE MAIN 387 GOVT,Dr,"42,278.00","1,19,217.72"
12-Apr-2017,BY CLG-259-           50754,Cr,"68,842.00","50,375.72"
12-Apr-2017,BY CLG-COB-          251639,Cr,"30,000.00","20,375.72"
12-Apr-2017,DILIP AJMERA  S/O JA,Dr,"2,89,868.00","3,10,243.72"`;

  var base64data = Utilities.base64Encode(csv_string); // encoded string
  
  var decoded = Utilities.base64Decode(base64data); // decoded string
  
  var string = Utilities.newBlob(decoded).getDataAsString(); // csv string

  var array = Utilities.parseCsv(string) // 2d array

  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(1,1,array.length,array[0].length).setValues(array);
}
```

[image]

[Here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1-pgfDaX5nVE2n_ASpoWen5ebVulJ1-aKFFgUN4MLK6Q/edit?usp=sharing) is my sheet.

Comment: having issue while parsing csv, facing the error Error Exception: Could not parse text. as my sample csv looks like [this](https://docs.google.com/document/d/12z_v54nMyui7nh5cwrLQF98AHwwuB7JQnvJ6_ULQuEA/edit)

Comment: Looks like there is a problem with how you get the CVS. It doesn't look well at some places. It contains a number of uncommon symbols like `^`, etc. But when I copy it from your Google Doc directly into the script the native Google csv parser get me no errors as you can see. All the 3000+ rows are parsed fine.

Comment: And one more thing. Your CSV is quite big. Over 3000 rows. It takes about 200 kilobytes as txt. Make sure that it doesn't exceed the limitation on the size of a string.

Comment: Thankyou for the detailed answer it worked, I will take the size into consideration.